Disable network "disconnect button" in kde ubuntu
Is there any way to disable network "disconnect button" in kubuntu KDE, or hide it? Can't find any information or resolution to make this happen. Has anyone done this? Is it possible to simply deactivate it or make it inactive?

I tried to find any information about it, but there is nothing.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
